# How to read the original local path of a file from chrome instead of chrome returning "fake path"?

Tags: html, google-chrome, chromium

I'm working on a web page.  In chrome, Is there a way to return original path of some file, rather than fake path. I need my page to read the local path which the user selects and that local user path will be sent to back end for some functionality.

Chrome always returns `C:/fakepath/text.txt` but I need actual path like `C:/users/abc/text.txt` (original path)

Is there a way to do that by **changing some chrome settings** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, security feature. And because it's a security feature, there's no way around it. disclosing the path could give away personally identifiable information such as the users real name (common account name) or the location of other similar files.